# ViewAllData or ViewAllRecords Required Error for Integration User

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, sharing-rule, insufficient-privileges

While trying to get case information using EmailMessage object using REST URL I am getting the below error:

```
**message**: ViewAllData or ViewAllRecords required to upsert by standard field
**errorCode**: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS

**REST API End Point** : /services/data/v52.0/sobjects/EmailMessage/MessageIdentifier/%ABCX.PROD.OUTLOOK.COM%3E
```

User is able to query the same record using SOQL, Then Why the issue is happening while REST Call.Also , Error message is about Upsert while I am using a GET Call.

Also what is the best practise to ensure access issue doesnt happen without using System Admin Profile for Integration User.

Its working when I give **View All Data** Permission which i donot want to do so.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upsert requires View All Data because otherwise the user would be allowed to violate sharing by finding a record match that they potentially shouldn't be able to see. This check occurs even before access to the specific record is checked. You don't need to use System Administrator, though, you can just add View All Email Message to a custom profile, or create a Permission Set that has this permission set, and then assign it to your integration user.

Comment: Thanks . There is no option I am getting to provide emailMessage object View All Data Access. Only option is at the the profile level that is working for the user . Secondly This is a GET Call then why this is accounted for UPSERT .